# Firefox - black bar obscuring tab bar when using 4K external monitor

Tags: macos, firefox, browser-tabs, 4k-resolution

Black bar covering tab bar in firefox:

[image]

A black bar covers my tab bar seemingly randomly. I've tried refresh, and I've disabled/enabled extensions. One temporary fix is to scale the resolution and then scale it back (forces a redraw I'm guessing). Often occurs when opening new tab, occasionally resolves upon closing tab. Cannot replicate in chrome/safari. Restarting does not resolve.

Is this something to do with 4K Monitor+Mac+Firefox?

Comment: You have a suspicious outer window with green menu in your screenshot. The black bar is the normal windows menu bar, which firefox overdraws (normally when you hit the alt key, the menu will appear). The suspicious window is hooking into the firefox process and this breaks the firefox draw routine.

Comment: @Yorik This is about OSX.

Comment: Do you have GPU acceleration enabled (`layers.acceleration.disabled`=false) ? What about the preference     `browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar` (both can be accessed using the URL `about:config`)

Comment: Some configurations of high-dpi simulate resolutions. Is your 4k external resolution a multiple of 2 of the native internal monitor resolution? (e.g. a 1920x1080 simulated size on a 3840 × 2160 is an even 2x multiplier)

Comment: @Yorik the green menu is OSX menubar (it is semi-transparent and is showing the green background). There is no change if the window is pulled from the top or opened away.

Comment: @Yorik yes it is X2 multiplier (it may even be an MST monitor, not sure.. It's a SK off-brand "QNIX").

Comment: @Yorik layers.accel is =false, browser.tabs. is True.

Answer (score 0):

@Gryph : I have the same problem on FireFox 49.0.1 on Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.3 (15D21) but I believe only when using "Scaled" - not when using "Default for Display".  I just tried your workaround and it works for me too.  I have a high-end 4k monitor though, not an off-brand.  Maximizing the window removes the black bar overlay.  Restoring causes it to return.  Does maximizing make a difference for you, @Gryph?

My settings are also:
layers.acceleration.disabled = false
browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar = true

Comment: Mine is an off brand, but I think it's something to do with the resolution as you say - when I'm at natural 4K this doesn't occur (1440p is my preferred rez). Since switching to el capitan, 1440p is no longer an option on this display (there's a lot of grumble about this on apple forums right now).